# Launch flask python file from main python file

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask python file that i want to open when i start the main python file.

```
main python file

start flask python file

continue with it's own independent processes (threading)
```

Which solution to take since i do not want the execution of the flask app to hinder the performance of the later processes. Not sure if i should do a subprocess or exec file?

both files are pretty independent of each other.

Comment: And what does the main file do ? Does it end ? Because you just want to run a server and another code next to , why just not doing it separatly ?

Comment: the flask file is launched and is interacted with to store data. the main file accesses this data via api from the flask file. So when the main file is finished processing the data received from the flask file both end/stop running.

Comment: 1. Use 2 different process (terminal, whatever) . 2. don't use the flask app because the code may be used directly, no need of a server. A server is ran to be here "all time" not for a short purpore
Use the code that access the data directly from the main code

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, you can create a daemon thread for flask and continue with the execution of main program.

If you have a `independent_module.py` like this:

```
# independent_module.py
# your independent functions
def start():
    pass
```

Then your main file would look something like this:

```
# main.py file

import threading               
from flask import Flask 
   
import main                  
app = Flask(__name__) 
     
@app.route("/health")          
def health():                  
     return "OK"

@app.route("/ping")
def ping():
    return "Et. Voila!!"

def run_server_api():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

def main():
    flask_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_server_api, daemon=True)
    flask_thread.start()

    # continue with your main program functions
    independent_module.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute main
    main()
```

You can simply execute `python main.py`